# What neural network topology is recommended to predict signals?

Tags: neural-networks, prediction

Assumed I have gathered some measures of a complex system and I want to train a neural network to predict certain measure outcomes based on some simulated inputs, what ANN layout would you recommend?

The inputs are unbound FP numbers, i.e. 0 to infinity, the outputs are mixed, i.e. some are ranged FP, others are unbound - so part of the problem is to represent possible outcomes if inputs are outside of the training data space

A simple example of the kind of problem I am looking at:
Predict the fuel consume of a car based on recorded (speed,consume) tuples, where training data would be various between 0 to 150km/h,  and then querying the ANN with input 220km/h

Comment: My guess is that a polynomial fit would be much better than an ANN in this case, but in the latter case the architecture shouldn’t be too important. Use a few hidden layers, ReLU activation, and whatever layer sizes empirically work for you. You might have more luck though if you ask Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you will be predicting several values or an actual signal. Because those are different problems.

If by several values you mean a continuous signal, I suggest the use of Reccurent Neural Networks (RNN) and/or Long Short Term Memory (LSTM). You should read on both and decide which suits your problem best.

As for predicting several values, I have never heard on a Neural network returning several values that are not homogeneous in type (this falls in the first suggestion). Therefore you will probably need to build a different model for each of your desired outputs.

I hope I understood your question, if not, feel free to edit and I will edit my answer accordingly.